# Can we achieve a file transfer from host to pod using openshift cronjob

Tags: cron, openshift, kubernetes-cronjob

We have a requirement where we need to drop a file from host machine to the container on regular intervals.

Since we are in proof of concept phase we are managing manually using `oc cp` or `oc sync` commands.  We came to know that openshift platform provides a facility of cronjobs and jobs.

Can such kind of requirement can be achieved using cronjobs provided by openshift?